# Angular conditional based on depth of item in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know if i'm phrasing this correctly - but essentially what I'm trying basically say is :

If this item has no parent (or is the highest level) then don't display. So my thinking was to try if !$parent (if no parent). Here's what I am looking at -

```
 <div ng-if-"!$parent">{{category.link}} </div>
```

(this does not work)

It is a recursive list tree (ng-repeats inside ng-repeats) and I basically don't want the top level to have the link attribute shown. I could set a boolean or something to just toggle it off on the most parent level BUT I'm wondering if it's possible to do it in this kind of way. Thanks!

Comment: The first element in the ng-repeat would not be parentless. Its parent would be the outer scope. The only parentless scope should be `$rootScope`.

Comment: usually fairly easy with some sort of `children.length` test

Comment: @charlietfl , could you elaborate? I've considered this, however I don't feel the children such a direct relationship as I'm trying to determine if it is just the highest level in the object, and some on that level have no children. Thanks!

Comment: well if it's recursive, template on top level will always be top level of object won't it? Then on recursive templates can simply add an attribute. Post more code. Is never easy to look up in objects/arrays, but is usually easy to know where recursion starts